# xml styleing-putting two layouts in the same spot

Tags: android, android-layout

here is my xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/down"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/down"
        android:src="@drawable/right" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/down"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/down"
        android:src="@drawable/left" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/up"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right"
        android:src="@drawable/up" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/down"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/up"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/down" />
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

i want to organize it the way that the linearlayout "'surface" and the linear layout "background" would be on the same spot in the screen, both of them filling all the spot left other then the top linear layout and the relative layout. and that the layout "surface" would be on top of the layout "backgrounf", i mean that what will be shown in "surface" will be over what is shown in "background".

the way it is now, it shows to diffrnet layouts not on the same spot,divideing all the left room into two equal parts, each layout (surfave and background) take one.

how do i do that?
Tnx for the help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put a layout on top of another layout, you have 2 good choices. First is FrameLayout, super-simple,  will just stack Views on top of each other. The other option is to stick with RelativeLayout, you'll get some more options/functionality.

If you choose RelativeLayout, you'll want to set both layouts to be in the same spot instead of next to each other.

If you had a background ImageView and wanted a textView on top of it, you might do something like this:

FrameLayout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:src="@android:drawable/gallery_thumb" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World" />
</FrameLayout>
```

RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:src="@android:drawable/gallery_thumb" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

(In this example, alignParentXXX isn't necessarily required, but I wanted to include it to be explicit that they overlap, even if the match_parent is changed to wrap_content)